# PHP Unexpected ":" on line 3 from the webcrawler example on

Tags: php, wamp

I'm working through the second example on http://tinyurl.com/7k6yk9y . Here it is:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = “http://www.tokyobit.com/”;
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
foreach($html->find(‘a’) as $link){
echo $link->href.”<br />”;
}
?>
```

I get the follow error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\wamp\www\crawler\example3.php on line 3
```

(The file is stored in the folder Crawler. Could anyone tell me why this is? I pretty much just copy and pasted from the website and the previous example worked. There is a comment with the same problem, but it isn't answer very well.

I am using the latest version of WAMP server.

Thank you!

Comment: The blog converted the regular quotes `"` & `‘` to special quote characters `“` & `’`.

Comment: @TimCooper always wondered, how do you type ‘ (special) instead of ' (regular)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use " or ' instead of “!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use single or double quotations marks when declaring text (in your case URL) as a variable, not an apostrophe. Above answers got it right, but just to add an explanation.
PHP doesnt see

$target_url = “http://www.tokyobit.com/”;

that as text and it sees // as u commenting out everything after in the same line out.
In other words PHP sees your code as

$target_url = “http:

Answer (score 1):

**You can also change the line 3 as:**

```
$target_url = 'http://www.tokyobit.com';
```

The single quotes ('..') can also be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 3 to

```
$target_url = "http://www.tokyobit.com/";
```

“ is not the same as "